# "socket hang up error" while hitting the remote server in node.js

Tags: node.js, remote-server

I have an app in which I need to hit the remote server for fetching the data and for that I use sample.js as a mediator for that. But when I run this file, I am getting the following error.

> socket hang up

My code in sample.js

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var http = require('https');

var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "hostname": "xxx",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/xxx",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "xxx",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-controller": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "xxx"
  }
};

var myToken = "";
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on("end", function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    myToken = body.toString();
    req.write(qs.stringify({
      glba: 'otheruse',
      dppa: 'none'
    }));
    req.end();
  });
});
```

I am not sure about this error, can anyone please suggest me help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the remote server if it is in your control. Normally this happens when server did not sent timely response and your socket just ended. It would be better if this is caught and retrial/queuing etc are used.

Also try having increased timeout in options. Might be server is responding a little late. Like this -

```
var options = { ... }
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // Usual stuff: on(data), on(end), chunks, etc...
});

req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(myTimeout);  
    socket.on('timeout', function() {
        req.abort();
    });
});

req.on('error', function(err) {
    if (err.code === "ECONNRESET") {
        console.log("Timeout occurs");
        //specific error treatment
    }
    //other error treatment
});

req.write('something');
req.end();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Aky_0788,I am actually new to this.Can you please explain about it 'Also try having increased timeout in options' and how can I increase timeout.....